# What's the difference between MultiLayerSpace.Builder.layer() and MultiLayerSpace.Builder.addLayer() in DL4J?

Tags: java, dl4j

I'm using Arbiter in DL4J for the first time to try and optimize a MultiLayerNetwork. My question is pretty straightforward: What is the difference between these two methods?
`MultiLayerSpace.Builder.addLayer(LayerSpace<?> layerSpace)`
`MultiLayerSpace.Builder.layer(LayerSpace<?> layerSpace)`

I've tried consulting [the builder's documentation](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/arbiter/MultiLayerSpace.Builder) but it provides no explanation. As far as I can tell, these two methods work in exactly the same way.

Comment: you are right, they do the same thing. See source code: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/Arbiter/blob/master/arbiter-deeplearning4j/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/arbiter/MultiLayerSpace.java#L201-L230

Comment: Interesting, thanks!